# How many unital $k$-subalgebras are there in $k^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field.
I would like to show that there are finitely many unital $k$-subalgebras of $k^n$.
Let $s_n$ be the number of unital $k$-subalgebras of $k^n$.
I would like to further show that $\sum \frac{s_n}{n!} x^n=e^{e^x-1}$.

Let $B$ be a unital subalgebra of $k^n$.
Based on the formula of the generating series to show,
it seems that the set of all $B$ is in bijection with the set of all partitions of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.
For example, if $n=3$,
then $B$ could (only) be of the form $\{(a,b,c):a,b,c\in k\}$,
$\{(a,a,b):a,b\in k\}$, $\{(a,b,a):a,b\in k\}$, $\{(b,a,a):a,b\in k\}$,
or $\{(a,a,a):a\in k\}$.
But it seems quite difficult to prove, even whether $s_n$ is finite.

Comment: Be more precise with the combinatorics. A subalgebra can have, e.g., the form $\left\{\left(a,b,a,b,c,b,b,c\right) \mid a,b,c\in k\right\}$. In general, the subalgebras are in one-to-one correspondence with the set partitions of the set $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$.

Comment: Given any equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$, the $n$-tuples $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \in k^n$ with $a_i=a_j$ whenever $i \sim j$ form a $k$-subalgebra. Conversely, does every subalgebra arise this way from an equivalence relation?

Comment: Does the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577340/isomorphic-subalgebras-of-kn-are-just-permutations-of-each-other answer your request?

Comment: Note that it is essential that $k$ be a field for the correspondence with equivalence relations to hold. If $k$ is merely a commutative ring, then the $k$-subalgebras of $k^2$ are in bijective correspondence with the ideals of $k$, of which there are more than just $B_2=2$ of them (where $B_2$ is the second Bell number).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The answer there did not show exactly why the correspondence between subalgebras and equivalence relations holds. My answer below includes the complicated details showing that the correspondence does in fact hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it is true that $s_n=B_n$, the $n$th Bell number (which is the number of equivalence relations on an $n$-element set).

Indeed, given any equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\{1,2,...,n\}$, one could define a unital subalgebra of $k^n$ consisting of all $n$-tuples $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ for which $a_i=a_j$ whenever $i \sim j$.

Conversely, given any unital subalgebra $B$ of $k^n$, one could define an equivalence relation $\sim_B$ where $i \sim_B j$ if and only if for all $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \in B$, one has $a_i=a_j$.

To see that the above operations are inverse to each other, suppose that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and $B$ is its associated unital subalgebra. Then, it is clear that $\sim \subseteq \sim_B$ by the definition of $B$. On the other hand, if $i \not\sim j$, then the $n$-tuple with $1$ in the $k$th component for $k \sim i$ and $0$s in all the other components is in $B$, but the $i$th and $j$th components are not equal, so $i \not\sim_B j$. So, $\sim = \sim_B$.

Now, let $B$ be a unital subalgebra and $\sim_B$ be its associated equivalence relation. Also, let $B'$ be the unital subalgebra associated with $\sim_B$. Then, it is clear from the definitions that $B \subseteq B'$.

The harder direction is to show that $B' \subseteq B$ and hence $B=B'$. Since $B$ is a unital subalgebra of $k^n$, it contains $(a, a, ..., a)$ for all $a \in k$.

It suffices to show that the $n$-tuple with $1$ in the $j$th component for $j \sim_B i$ and $0$s in all the other components (henceforth to be denoted as $\mathbf{b}_i$) is in $B$ for all indices $i$, as the $\mathbf{b}_i$s are easily seen to generate $B'$ as a unital subalgebra. If $j \sim_B i$ for all indices $j$, then $\mathbf{b}_i=(1, 1, ..., 1)$, which of course is in $B$ since $B$ is a unital subalgebra. Otherwise, let $j$ be an index for which $j \not\sim_B i$. Then, by the definition of $\sim_B$, there is some $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \in B$ for which $a_j \ne a_i$. Since $(a_j, a_j, ..., a_j) \in B$ by the above remark, one may subtract $a_j$ from all of the components and then multiply all of them by $(a_i-a_j)^{-1}$ to get an $n$-tuple in $B$ with the $i$th and $j$th components equal to $1$ and $0$ respectively. Next, repeat this process for the other indices $k$ with $k \not\sim_B i$. After that, the product of all of the resulting $n$-tuples would then be equal to $\mathbf{b}_i$, so $\mathbf{b}_i \in B$ since $B$ is a unital subalgebra.

This shows that $B' \subseteq B$ and hence $B=B'$.

Comment: I figured it out myself. It roughly goes like this. Let $[i]$ denote the equivalence class of $i$. There exists $a\in B$ such that $a_{[i]}\ne a_{[j]}$ for $[i]\ne [j]$. We may assume $a_{[i]}\ne 0$ for all $i$ because $q:=(1,1,\dots,1)\in B$. Then by scaling $q$ and adding to $a$ and repeating this for several times, we eventually get that for all $i$, there is $b\in B$ such that $b_{[j]}=\delta_{ij}$. These $b$ generate $B$ as a vector space, so $B$ must be of the desired form.

Comment: @durianice Your idea won't quite work as $B$ is a unital subalgebra, not just a vector subspace. Anyway, I have updated my answer to include the details showing that $B' \subseteq B$. The proof won't work if $B$ is merely a vector subspace containing $(1, 1, ..., 1)$.

Comment: I don't see how your method is much different than mine though. My $b$ (which depends on $i$) is just your $b_i$. Only difference is I scale the identity element and you scale $(a_1,\dots, a_n)$ directly.