Confusion about rings and ideals and how ideals are always subrings.
I've been studying rings and ideals recently and was told that all ideals are subrings. However, I seem to have been able to do the following to show that leads to an ideal being the ring itself. That is, if $R$ is a ring and $I \subseteq R$ an ideal of the ring that also happens to be a subring (which I've been told always happens for ideals), then we have $I=R$. To prove this, we know $(I,\cdot)$ is a submonoid of $(R,\cdot)$ since $I$ is a subring of $R$. This implies that the multiplicative identity $1$ is in $I$. Let $x \in R$. Then by definition, $1x=x \in I$ since $I$ is an ideal. Therefore, $R \subseteq I$, which means $I=R$.
Of course, this can't be the case. What I'm primarily confused about is essentially how, from the definition of an ideal, we can show such an ideal is also a subring. I assume to show a subset is a subring, we must show it is a subgroup of the additive group and a submonoid of the multiplicative monoid, but this seems to lead to $I=R$.

The definition of a ring varies from place to place - sometimes a ring need not have a multiplicative identity.

@Ijfirth I'm inclined to agree, but the textbook I'm using defines a ring as having one ("Basic Algebra 1" by Jacobson), so should I assume that if a ring is defined as in the book, not all ideals are subrings?

Indeed, otherwise (as your proof showed), every ideal would be the whole ring.

Every ideal is a subrng, but the only ideal that is a subring is the whole ring.

This is an issue in the definition of "subring," which I am sorry to report can vary from author to author. Some authors don't require rings to have multiplicative identities, and some authors don't require subrings to share multiplicative identities. Personally I think this definition is completely wrong, and the argument why is carefully explained by Bjorn Poonen in his Why all rings should have a $1$. But it is used in some contexts, e.g. operator algebras.
What is true with any definition is that ideals are closed under multiplication (in the noncommutative case we need to specify two-sided ideals here). It is also possible for a proper ideal $I$ to have a multiplicative identity that differs from the multiplicative identity $1_R$ in the larger ring $R$. However, with what I consider to be the standard definition of "subring" (that it must contain $1_R$), the only ideal containing $1_R$ is the unit ideal.
Here is a nice example of a statement that is only true with this definition of "subring": let $X$ be a finite set and $K$ be a field, and consider the $K$-algebra $K^X$. Then $K$-subalgebras of $K^X$ are in natural bijection with equivalence relations on $X$. This is false if you don't require subalgebras to share the multiplicative identity and you get a slightly stranger and more annoying statement instead.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794216/how-many-unital-k-subalgebras-are-there-in-kn for the proof that the unital $K$-subalgebras of $K^X$ correspond bijectively with the equivalence relations on $X$.
